# Here Android SDK - how to build a sample app?

Tags: android, here-api

I am building sample app from HERE_Android_SDK_Premium_v3.8.0.104

After following required steps from https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/app-simple.html application fails on emulator with error:

> I/System.out: ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment

It looks like HERE SDK failed to integrate:

- AndroidManifest.xml cannot
  resolve service name "com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
- BasicMapActivity.java cannot resolve HERE package
  "com.here.android.mpa"

What do I do wrong?

**Edit from 14 September 2018:**

After invalidating cache and restarting IDE packages resolved successfully. Application still fails, log:

```
D/gralloc_ranchu: Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected. Loading gralloc.default.so from /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.goldfish.default.so...
                  gralloc.default.so not found in /vendor. Trying /system/lib/hw/gralloc.goldfish.default.so...
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:42): avc: denied { search } for name="graphics" dev="tmpfs" ino=240 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:graphics_device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
I/Choreographer: Skipped 290 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/System.out: ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment
```

Comment: To those who downvote: it's not a problem if you are not familiar with this topic. Better ask a question next time.

Comment: Do you know the basics?

Comment: @AmeerHamza Basics of what?

Comment: The basics of android development and the understanding of IDE

Comment: @AmeerHamza Firstly, IDE is irrelevant for this question as sample app is not restricted to particular environment but based on a build script, therefore build should pass with or without IDE. Secondly, what topic of Android development are you interested in, please clarify

Comment: The errors you are indicating are a result of a missing HERE Android SDK library (HERE-sdk.aar) file.  The instructions in https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/app-simple.html is using Android Studio as the IDE but whatever you choose (Eclipse or Android Studio), you need to make sure that the library is imported before you execute the build.  Please review the section "Import the HERE SDK Android Archive" and double check if you've missed anything.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport AAR library was in place, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on HereMaps Android for past 2+years, I hope I can help you to debug.

First, search for the method `onEngineInitializationCompleted`. It has the `Error error` as a parameter.

Second, try to print the error in Android log as `error.name()`.
This log message will tell you the exact problem.

Finally, Sample Here Maps app need the location, write storage permission granted by default.

I assume you have created a sample trail project on here maps site and replaced the api_id, app_code,license_key in the sample code.

I strongly recommend following this [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html) to get started with Here Maps Android.